cannot verify einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr's certificate, issued by ‘CN=GeoTrust TLS ECC CA G1,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
When I writing this url on safari, its content appears correctly:
https://einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr/InvoiceService/ServiceContract/InvoiceService.svc

But when I use
wget https://einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr/InvoiceService/ServiceContract/InvoiceService.svc 

in terminal on macOS Sonoma 14.0 and ubuntu 22.04, I got this error:
--2024-08-30 04:57:06--  https://einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr/
Resolving einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr (einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr)... 90.158.104.38
Connecting to einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr (einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr)|90.158.104.38|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr's certificate, issued by ‘CN=GeoTrust TLS ECC CA G1,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to einvoiceserviceturmobtest.luca.com.tr insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.


The server setup is broken as can be seen by checking the site with SSLLabs:

This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

This is a problem which needs to be fixed at the server. Unfortunately it is common so browsers work around it, but other programs don't. Which also means that it goes often unnoticed by the server admins which might only check with a browser.

